# Terminal window close eventhandler in python for linux

Tags: python, linux, signals

My Python program is running in ubuntu terminal window.If the terminal window is directly closed, need an event to occur and in that event i will send a message to server that application is exited. I tried with the following and it doesn't work.

```
def window_handler(self):
   CommandExecutor.processCommands(0, ProjectConstants.EXIT)             

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, window_handler)
```

I have tried other signals too... How could i achieve this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Closing a terminal will send `SIGHUP` to the processes which have that terminal's pseudo-tty as their controlling terminal.

Thus catching `SIGHUP` instead of `SIGTERM` should work.

I am unsure if there are some special considerations that you need to take in account when handling signals in Python, but that is a topic for another question. :)